# Referencing multiple buttons efficiently in Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-imagebutton

Hey I'm just a week into Kotlin but I'm struggling with something now. I got this list where I want to put 20 ImageButtons in efficiently with not writing everything individually. I gave all ImageButtons an id that only differs with an integer at the end, for example: takLinks1, takLinks2, takLinks3, ...

I'm trying to do it with a while loop but I can't seem to find the right syntax for Kotlin to do it. Does anyone have an idea how I could tackle this?

```
private lateinit var takkenLinks: ArrayList<ImageButton>
private fun populateButtonList(){
    var i = 1
    while (i < 21) {
        val takLinks$i = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id."takLinks$i")
        takkenLinks.add(taklinks$i)
    }
}
```

Comment: The better way to do this is instead of putting all the buttons in your layout, put a RecyclerView in your Layout and create your Buttons in the RecyclerView.Adapter. It's not trivial to learn how to use RecyclerView, but you eventually will have to learn it anyway since it is so widely used.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll take a look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually landed on this code for now, making an array of id's and then just loop through the array and adding each id to the ArrayList and this seems to do the trick. ( I also divided the 20 to 2 sets of 10 )

```
private fun populateButtonList(){
    val idL = arrayOf(R.id.takLinks1, R.id.takLinks2, R.id.takLinks3, R.id.takLinks4, R.id.takLinks5,
            R.id.takLinks6, R.id.takLinks7, R.id.takLinks8, R.id.takLinks9, R.id.takLinks10)
    val idR = arrayOf(R.id.takRechts1, R.id.takRechts2, R.id.takRechts3, R.id.takRechts4, R.id.takRechts5,
            R.id.takRechts6, R.id.takRechts7, R.id.takRechts8, R.id.takRechts9, R.id.takRechts10)
    var i = 0
    while (i < 10) {
        val takLinks = findViewById<ImageButton>(idL[i])
        val takRechts = findViewById<ImageButton>(idR[i])
        giveClickListeners(takLinks, i, "wij")
        giveClickListeners(takRechts, i, "zij")
        takkenLinks.add(takLinks)
        takkenRechts.add(takRechts)
        i += 1
    }
}
```